# IBM Integration Bus - FileInput Node - Change mqsiarchive Folder Name/Location

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

In a message flow, for a file transfer use-case, when I use the `FileInput` node, it automatically creates the following folders `mqsibackout` and `mqsitransitin`.

Is there a way I can change these folder names, location by a local environment variable setting?

My issue is, I have to pick a file from a IBM-i system, and it has a 8 character folder name limitation. Is it possible to change this folder names?

IBM App Connect Enterprise version 11.0.0.6

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Fair question. IBM does not document any such override mechanism, and a quick Google search did not turn up any hits either. I suggest that you either

a) contact IBM support and ask if they have any suggestions or

b) talk to the i-series team and ask them if they can use a different filesystem. They have probably had the same question from other applications. Maybe they can move the directory to IFS instead of QDLS?

Comment: Thanks a lot kimbert, I'll check and update if I find anything interesting.